# Modal Textarea Editing cursor goes to the last line

Tags: html, modal-dialog, textarea

When i want to edit textarea into modal, always cursor goes to the last line. How can i disable it?

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Not Düzenle</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <textarea id="eventNote" rows="5" wrap="soft" class="form-control text-uppercase">ALBÜM MODELİ WOODY 2 LACİVERT RENK OLACAK.</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>
      <button type="button" id="editNoteToOrganisationButton" class="btn btn-success">Düzenle</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not leaving out any JavaScript or CSS? Assuming you're using bootstrap based on the classes, everything seems to be working as expected.
This is the expected behavior when clicking into textboxes so in terms of UX, you probably shouldn't try to change this.